# Broken packages for installing python3-pip in Ubuntu16.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pip, ubuntu-14.04, apt

I am trying to install python3-pip as

```
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Then I have error as

```
reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3-pip : Depends: python3-setuptools but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: python3-dev (>= 3.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+The+following+packages+have+unmet+dependencies

Comment: I followed these two commands `sudo apt-get install python-pkg-resources=3.3-1ubuntu1` and `sudo apt-get install python-setuptools` as mentioned in the assumed duplicate link. But still have the same error.

Comment: [sudo apt-mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52874877/7976758). [How do I resolve `The following packages have unmet dependencies`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26594352/7976758).